# migrating a document library which has folder structure in it from sharepoint 2013 to sharepoint 2016 without using 3rd party tools

Tags: migrate

How to migrate a document library including content (files and folder structure in it) from SharePoint 2013 on-premise to SharePoint 2016 on-premise without using 3rd party tools?

Comment: You can migrate the whole site collection where the document library are. It's necessary for you migrate just the document library?

Comment: Could you share both steps to migrate the whole site collection of library and library alone? My library is large with many subfolders and unique permissions for each folders and files.

Comment: Yes I'll elaborate answer based on that. Asuming both Sharepoint's instances 2013 and 2016 are allready installed.

Comment: Yes, we have both sharepoint 2013 and 2016 on-premise farms installed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the Explorer view to move from one library to another, ensure that you have same columns in target and source to preserve metadata. If library is large it may not be best way, if you hit a problem it will stop and it might difficult to know where it failed,  or how to start from that point on.
2. Another way would be to create custom PowerShell script.